# angularjs How can I access the ng-repeat array from within my item template

Tags: angularjs

I want to do this...

```
<span ng-repeat="item in array1" ng-include="'genericItemTemplate.html'">
```

and this...

```
<span ng-repeat="item in array2" ng-include="'genericItemTemplate.html'">
```

and then in the genericItemTemplate.. do this...

```
[{{$index + 1}} of {{someArrayreference.length}}]
```

can I reference the array of the ng-repeat within the template?

see also my longer post... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/y_KuX0HRQ_U

and my plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/dY7M76kPyLeK0fvVZhvB

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use onload, an ng-include optional parameter:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in personlist=friends" ng-include="'myGenericTemplate.html'"
    onload="len=friends.length"></li>

<li ng-repeat="person in personlist=collegues" ng-include="'myGenericTemplate.html'"
    onload="len=collegues.length"></li>

[{{$index + 1}} of {{len}}] {{person.name}}
```

Output:

```
I have friends. They are:
[1 of 2] John a boy who is 25 years old.
[2 of 2] Mary a girl

I also have collegues. They are:
[1 of 3] Hoolio a boy who is 42 years old.
[2 of 3] Kitty a girl
[3 of 3] Marge a girl
```

Comment: aha, the onload works on the inner scope, nice!  I'm a gonna try that thanks.

Comment: The onload creates the `len` property on the scope where ng-include is used -- in this case, it is the ng-repeat scope created for that person/iteration.  The ng-include child scope can see `len` on its parent scope via prototypal inheritance.